# Should i include all the script tags for all the controllers in index.html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm creating a SPA with angularjs and have a separate folder for each feature in the administration panel that contains the partial view and the controller like so:
[files and folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GpoU.png)

[image]

The problem i'm facing now is i find my self having to add a script tag which references all the .JS files of all the controllers.

```html
    <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="views/clients/clients_controller.js"></script>
    <script src="views/clients/orders_controller.js"></script>
```

This means that if the user is viewing the client data, the whole scripts for the orders, the products, etc..... will be loaded.

Now if I reached a point where i have about 100 or so controllers in my app it will be a huge amount of JS scripts loaded for no reason at all.

I'm sorry I've been programming for about 17 years, started with php to python and I've used angularjs before as a part of ionic framework app but never as a web application 
also it's my first time ever I ask a question on stack overflow so please  bear with me and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are worried abut the amount of requests your server will take then there are ways to bundle your code depending on the structure of your code. You can also split your bundles in ways that your clients only request what you need and nothing else.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, please can you add some more details about bundling my code?
also, it's not just the amount of requests to the server that bothers me, I'm feeling as having all the business logic of my app present all the time at the user's disposal is not the best thing to do right?

Comment: One of the limitations of the AngularJS framework is that HTML is lazy loaded but controllers, directives, and services are not. (They are lazy instantiated but not lazy loaded.) There is third-party code for lazy loading, bundling, and minification. Making a recommendation or writing a tutorial is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem we can use [`oclazyload`](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad):

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router","oc.lazyLoad"]);
```

In this example we have `ui-router` to changes route and with each route we load state files as controller or service

```
$stateProvider.state("main", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "view.html",
    controller: "mainController",
    resolve: {
        loadMyCtrl: ["$ocLazyLoad", function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                files: ["mainController.js"] //["mainController.js", "mainService.js"]
            });
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can lazy load controllers without using any library.

First get a reference of your control provider where you bootstrap the app. You can attach this to your app object itself.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', [])
.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
    myApp.controlProvider = $controllerProvider;
}]);
```

Now put your controller in to .js or inside a script in an html file you want to add to the DOM - or, maybe in a route.

```
myApp.controlProvider.register('my-lazy-controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}])
```

If you don't want to use this in a route, load this new script or html using an appropriate method. You can use jQuery `.load()` if your have the controller in an html file or jQuery `getScript()` for loading .js file